# How to display edit and details on a single view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, strongly-typed-view

I am looking for a partially edit my model - the scenario is i want to display 5 fields and ,2 fields should be editable, and when post happens it should update the editable fields, Strongly type view provide either fully editable view or detail view , how can i have both in conjunction . Any advice or help will be appreciated.

```
 <tr><td>Booking ID</td><td><%: Model.ID %></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Transaction No.</td><td><%: Model.TransactionNumber %>&nbsp;(<%: Model.PaymentProvider %>)</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Date</td><td><%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DateAdded) %></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Name</td><td><%: ViewBag.account.FirstName %>&nbsp;<%: ViewBag.account.LastName %></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                <%: Html.Label("Event") %>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                <%: Model.Event.Name %><%: Model.Event.Description %>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td valign="top">Address</td><td><%= HtmlFormatting.FormatAddress(ViewBag.address)%></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Cost</td><td>&pound;<%: String.Format("{0:F}", Model.Cost) %></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Status</td><td><%: ViewBag.status %></td></tr>
```

Thnx

Comment: Can we have some code examples please?

Comment: Oh kay... So what do you need to be updated and where is your `<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { }` block and How are you using the MVC3 `ViewBag` property in an MVC2 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is all wrong here. First of all, don't use `<table>`'s  everywhere for layout, you can use the `MVC` template, just float the `div` tags left.

You need a `ViewModel` within which you can reference your `Booking` object which I assume is a database object?

Something like...

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
   public Booking Booking { get; set; }
}
```

And when you call your `View` from your controller pass it in

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(new BookingViewModel());
}
```

Then you can add a `Post` action result to your controller within which you can update your properties

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(BookingViewModel model)
{
   //Update your properties
   return View(model);
}
```